# Altium 17: Smart Grid Insert: Parameters

Tags: altium, pins

When generating schematic symbols with large pin numbers (like µCs), we use an excel sheet to generate the Pins via smart grid insert.

The problem is that though the column identifiers match in the "grid insert" menu, after confirmation, when the new pins show up in the editor, neither Pin length, font nor the custom parameters are applied.
Only Pin name, designator and the positioning coordinates are correct.

In the Default primitives everything is set up correctly for a new pin.

What could cause that problem?

Comment: Have you opened a ticket with Altium support?

Comment: No, but I probably will. I think that the parameter editing in general is buggy/not implemented properly.